# Version Control Best Practices for Supporting/Required Software

Tags: version-control

I have a small C# project developed by someone on our team who left. I'm getting it into version control. The application requires the following:

- Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.2
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x64 Redistributable – 10.0.30319
- MySQL Community Server 5.6.36

My question is, is it a good idea to drop the install files for this supporting software into version control (I'm using GitLab)? Or is there some better way of managing supporting/required software?

Thanks